# Angular(8) NgbModal DB insert and same data will refresh on parent page component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap, page-refresh

In my Angular (8) using [NgbModal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples).
parent page, one of component getting the data from http service (java and mysql db) as list.
and on submit of modal, it will insert a record in same table of mysql db.
now after Modal submit and dismiss, how to refresh/update the component list data with new data.

Parent Component -> opening the modal component

"selectedName" fetch from DB and displaying in parent component.

```
 openEditProfilePage() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(EditProfileComponent, { size: 'xl', scrollable: true });
    modalRef.componentInstance.selectedName = this.selectedName;

  }
```

Child component get value of selectedName from parent, and in a form update to apend some string and save.

```
 onSave(form: FormGroup) {

    if (form.valid) {

      this.nameService.editName(form.value).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.modalService.dismissAll();
        },
        error => {
          this.showError(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Now in child it will update the name in DB.so after dismissAll, modal/popup will be closed, and same time want to display the updated name, in parent component.

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far

Comment: edited the qs, to add some code

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the docs, it seems that you need to use the result promise provided by the NgbModalRef (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalRef). The promise gets resolved(or rejected) when the modal closes, therefore you will be able to load the new list at that point. For Example: 
In your parent page component.ts

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
        //call the method of refreshing your list here
    }, (reason) => {
        //called if the modal was dismissed for some reason
    });
  }
```

In your modal component html

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <!-- modal.close will cause the result promise to get resolved therefore executing the block of code that will refresh the items list -->
    <button type="button"(click)="onClose()">Save</button>
  </div>
```

In your modal component ts
you will have to inject the service inside the component of the modal in order to use the method you want

```
export class ModalComponent{
  constructor(private myHttpService: MyHttpService)\

  onClose(){
     this.myHttpService.methodToRefreshList()
     // close modal
  }
```

}

Comment: Hi Manos, thanks for answer, also in modal html, in (click) how to call my service method (who will do the db update).(click)="modal.close('Save click')" here.